# Pygit2 - Merging a branch with no fast forward

Tags: python, git, merge, libgit2, pygit2

I am essentially trying to do a "git merge --no-ff branch" to merge my branch back in.  Looking at the Pygit2 documentation, I am not entierly sure what the correct way to do this is.  The direct thought would be to do something like this:

```
repo.merge(branch.target)
```

However, I do not see any options for merging with no-fastforward.  Has anyone extensively used pygit2 that can give me any insight?  All the help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: it seems like your only option might be to override the GIT_MERGE_OPTS_INIT libgit2 constant

Answer (score 3):

> However, I do not see any options for merging with no-fastforward.

That is because, from the [pygit2 merge documentation](https://github.com/libgit2/pygit2/blob/master/docs/merge.rst):

> it only does the merge, **does not commit nor update the branch reference in the case of a fastforward**.

That means you can then decide to create a new commit once the merge itself is done.

> You can now inspect the index file for conflicts and get back to the user to resolve if there are.
>   Once there are no conflicts left, you can create a commit with these two parents.

```
other_branch_tip = '5ebeeebb320790caf276b9fc8b24546d63316533'
repo.merge(other_branch_tip)

user = repo.default_signature()
tree = repo.index.write_tree()
new_commit = repo.create_commit('HEAD', user, user, tree,
                                [repo.head.target, other_branch_tip])
```

Comment: Indeed, there is no option because it's the *only* merge that exists.